# Pointer arithmetic with pointer to pointer to double

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to understand what happens when I execute this

```
#include <stdio.h>

const int MAX = 3;

int main () {

   //double  var[] = {10.0, 100.1, 200.2};
   double  var[3];
   int  i;
   double *ptr;
   double **ptr2;


   for(i=0;i<MAX;i++)var[i] = 10.0*(double)(i+1);
   /* let us have array address in pointer */
   ptr = var;
   ptr2 = &ptr;

   for ( i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {

      printf("Address of var[%d] = %x\n", i, *ptr2 );
      printf("Value of var[%d] = %f\n", i, **ptr2 );

      /* move to the next location */
      ptr2++;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

This code snippet gives a seg fault at the second iteration

```
Address of var[0] = b0e04370                                                                                                                                                                 
Value of var[0] = 10.000000                                                                                                                                                                  
Address of var[1] = 0
```

However this works if instead of calling `ptr2` we call `ptr`

```
for ( i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {

 printf("Address of var[%d] = %x\n", i, ptr );
 printf("Value of var[%d] = %f\n", i, *ptr );

  /* move to the next location */
  ptr++;
}
```

giving

```
Address of var[0] = 3e9e89a0                                                                                                                                                                 
Value of var[0] = 10.000000                                                                                                                                                                  
Address of var[1] = 3e9e89a8                                                                                                                                                                 
Value of var[1] = 20.000000                                                                                                                                                                  
Address of var[2] = 3e9e89b0                                                                                                                                                                 
Value of var[2] = 30.000000
```

Comment: `ptr2++` steps `ptr2` forwards so that it points to the next pointer in memory after `ptr1`. But there is no pointer there; `ptr1` is not an array element. Perhaps you wanted `(*ptr2)++`?

Comment: Also, `for(int i;i<3;i++)var[i] = 10.0*(double)(i+1);` this does not guarantees that `i` is set to `0` when the loop is entered, which brings in Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: `for(int i;i<3;i++)var[i] ` causes undefined behaviour, use of uninitialized variable `i`

Comment: @WedaPashi Sorry, that was a typo copying and pasting

Comment: @squeamishossifrage You are right. I wanted that and I tried `*ptr2++` but it did not work.

Comment: You should go through the warning/error what compiler complains about and learn to use gdb and debug the program.

Comment: No `pointer to pointer to array` here! `double**` is a pointer to pointer to `double`, nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: @alk Correct, my bad. Updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It segfaults because the next address doesn't really hold anything.

I changed the loop to this and now it works the way you expect it to:

```
/* let us have array address in pointer */
ptr = var;
ptr2 = &ptr;

for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++) 
{
    printf("Address of var[%d] = 0x%x\n", i, (void*)*ptr2 );
    printf("Value of var[%d] = %f -- using ptr\n", i, *ptr);
    printf("Value of var[%d] = %f -- using ptr2\n", i, **ptr2);
    ptr++;
    // This updates ptr2, which was missed out
    ptr2 = &ptr;
}
```

With this it prints the following:

```
Address of var[0] = a313c9b0
Value of var[0] = 10.000000 -- using ptr
Value of var[0] = 10.000000 -- using ptr2
Address of var[1] = a313c9b8
Value of var[1] = 20.000000 -- using ptr
Value of var[1] = 20.000000 -- using ptr2
Address of var[2] = a313c9c0
Value of var[2] = 30.000000 -- using ptr
Value of var[2] = 30.000000 -- using ptr2
```

---

The reason your code segfaults at *second* iteration (and not at first) is

```
ptr = var;
ptr2 = &ptr;
```

With these two lines, `ptr2` not holds the address of `ptr` while `ptr` is pointing to `var[0]`

Lets see the second iteration now with the updated code:

```
ptr++;
```

which makes `ptr` to point to `var[1]`

```
ptr2 = &ptr;
```

which makes `ptr2` to hold the address of `ptr` which now point to `var[1]`.
I guess this explains. May be you could try the third iteration yourself.

Comment: C *only* know to print addresses of `void*`s. To do C defines to `p` conversion specifier. To print a pointer to any other type cast it to `void*`: `printf("Address of var[%d] = %p\n", i, (void*) *ptr2 );` Any other approach invokes the infamous Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: @alk: Thanks for the input, to be honest I didn't know that.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: `%lf` instead of `%f` should fix it? Since, `ptr` is a `double` pointer

Comment: No, you were fine and I'm senile.... If you dereference and are sending a `double` to `%f`, you are fine. You only need `%lf` on input (like `scanf`, etc..), output with `printf` handles `doubles` without the `l` modifier.

Comment: Thanks @DavidC.Rankin. I didn't know that either.